# How to use cookie csrf in django 1.11?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf

Hello I have a frontend application which was migrated to django and for csrf protection I am using the methodology of copying csrf token from cookies to header of my post request. Django keeps complaining about invalid csrf token despite that the request contais the csrf token from cookies.
In my `settings.py` I have explicitly specified:

`CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False`

to make sure that cookie-based csrf is used according [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax)

and the request header that gets the cookie csrf is:

`HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN`

The cookie is present and copied to the above header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` is the wrong request header name. The [correct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_HEADER_NAME) name is `X-CSRFToken`. Django converts *HTTP request header names* into *Python dictionary keys* by:

> converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores, and adding an 'HTTP_' prefix to the name.

Unfortunately that transformation can lead to confusion.